# Why is my telegram bot only reply to "/" and not plain text in a group?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

So, I'M trying to write a simple bot that everytime someone in the chat sends a text "I am" then the bot will reply "I am".
Here is the code I have so far using pytelegrambotapi:

```
    API_Key = "5*******2:AAH**************************o"
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_Key)

    @bot.message_handler(regexp="I am")
    def message(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "I am")

    bot.infinity_polling()
```

The bot for some reason answers to "/I am" but not to "I am". only when it is like a command with "/".

How can my bot send a message if a user just sends "I am"?
In private chat everything works. only in groups it is like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your bot settings using [BotFather in Telegram](https://t.me/BotFather).
Go to bot > bot settings > group privacy > turn off.
In this way, the bot will receive all messages, even if not starting with the command prefix `/`.

For detailed informations see this [official link about messages received by bots](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#what-messages-will-my-bot-get).

Comment: Did it. Still not working :( 
"Privacy mode is disabled for *bot*"

Comment: Ok, so there must be something to configure with the library you are using. When I worked with Telegram bots I wrote my own C# library, so I can't help you with Python, but I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: Also, can you post your full code?